# Fetch not working for uploading image react-native

Tags: node.js, react-native, multer

I am using `react-native-sketch-canvas` for signature pad and then saving signature image to **device storage** and getting the file path in response. When click on save, I am making fetch request to upload that saved image to node server. I used **multer** at **node js** side. I used below fetch code at `react-native`.

```
var data = new FormData(); 
data.append('file', {   
  uri: filepath, /* /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/RNSketchCanvas/image.png */
  name: 'image.png', 
  type: 'image/png'
});

fetch('http://apiUrl/api/upload',{   
    headers: {    
        'Accept': 'application/json', 
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    method: 'POST', 
    body: data
});
```

and code at my **node js(multer)** side.

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, __dirname+'/../files/');
  }
});
const storageMulter = multer({ 
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, true);
  }
});
var uploadConfig = storageMulter.single('file');
uploadConfig(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err) {
          handleErrors(res, err)
    } else {
          res.json(req.file.filename);
    }
})
```

if i send the **body = ""**, then it is giving me the "boundary not found" error. If i send **data** into body, it is not hitting the api.

Please help where i am wrong.

Comment: can you remove `Content-Type` from request headers and try again?

Comment: @amir, tried. But not working.

Comment: Is this iOS? If so, maybe the platform isn't letting you to do a request on http protocol. It needs to be whitelisted in the `Info.Plist` file.

Comment: @parohy, I can see in the logging from the node js side. I am not getting any upload api request. And this is android not iOS.

Comment: Give `rn-fetch-blob` or `react-native-fs` a try.